# Send data from blade to onclick function's parameters

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel

I'm having this problem, let me show you my code first:

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
<tr>
 <td>{{ $category->category_name }}</td>
  <td>{{ $category->category_description }}</td>
    <td>
    <button type="button"
        id="{{ $category->id }}"
       class="btn btn-info"
       onClick="{{category_manage(this, $category)}}"
    >Update / Delete</button>
  </td>
 </tr>
@endforeach

// jQuery
function category_manage(id, payload) {
  // payload is the category details that i send through second parameters
  console.log(id, payload);
}
```

Is there any way I could do this in Laravel and jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely. Use:

```php
    <button type="button"
        id="{{ $category->id }}"
        class="btn btn-info"
        onClick="category_manage('{{ $category->id }}', '{{ json_encode($category) }}')">
        Update / Delete
    </button>
```

.....

```html
    <script>
        function category_manage(id, payload) {
            console.log(id, JSON.parse(payload));
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: i still got error :/, saying "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: /media/mhdiiilham/HDD/klikACC/backend-live/resources/views/oblagio/blog/index.blade.php)"

Comment: It's work. I almost creating new pages just for update :D. It's very helpful

Comment: Glad to help. Keep doing it

Answer (score 0):

This will pass the parameters properly to your Javascript function:

```
onClick="category_manage('{{$category->id}}','{{$category}}')}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "this" in this scope.

Just use:

```
onClick="category_manage('{{$category->id}}','{{$category}}')}}"
```

Should work properly.

Comment: Yeah, i tried use "this"  and all i got is the button html xD

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you could do it more separated like the following example.

```php
@foreach ($categories as $category)
<tr>
  <td>{{ $category->category_name }}</td>
  <td>{{ $category->category_description }}</td>
  <td>
    <button 
      type="button"
      id="{{ $category->id }}"
      class="btn btn-info"
      data-category="{{ $category }}">
        Update / Delete
    </button>
  </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.btn[data-category]').on('click', tableButton);

  function tableButton(event) {
    var elem = $(event.target);
    var id = elem.attr('id');
    var payload = elem.data('category');

    console.log(id + " " + payload);
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be implemented by using the jQuery event like the following example.

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
<tr>
 <td>{{ $category->category_name }}</td>
  <td>{{ $category->category_description }}</td>
    <td>
    <button type="button"
        id="{{ $category->id }}"
       class="btn btn-info submitBtn"
       data-category="{{$category}}"
    >Update / Delete</button>
  </td>
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(document).on('click','.submitBtn',function(){
   console.log(this.attr('id'),this.data('category'));
 });
});
```