# Display one attribute to group others around it in foreach loop PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my project, all users are stored in the `user` table. The ones who are suppliers, their user key goes into the `supplier` table.

Each product can have multiple variations. The key product goes into the `productattribute` table.

Each supplier can have multiple products with multiple attributes.

So there is a many to many table of product attributes & suppliers named `productsupplier`.

I want to give the option to the user to make a new Purchase Order.
The Purchase Order will be for the supplier.

The user will select the supplier and then all the products that are assigned to him will show up.

The problem is that a product with the same name can have different attributes. Therefore, when I write the code for the products belonging to a supplier to show up, one product (which has different variations) shows up multiple times.
I have been struggling to use **distinct** or **unique** functions to show the name of one product once only, but since it's in a **foreach**  loop, it doesn't work.

Here's the code:

```
public function new_po_next(Request $request)
{
    $product = array();
    $supplier = \App\supplier::where('user_id', $request->supplier)->first();
    $productsupplier = \App\productsupplier::where('supplier_id', $supplier->id)->get();

    foreach ($productsupplier as $ps) {
        $productattribute = \App\productattribute::where('id', $ps->productattribute_id)->first();

        $prod = \App\product::where('id', $productattribute->product_id)->first();
        $product [] = [
            'prod_supp_id' => $ps->id,
            'prod_supp_prodattid' => $ps->productattribute_id,
            'prod_supp_cost' => $ps->cost,
            'prod_att_id' => $productattribute->id,
            'prod_att_color' => $productattribute->color_id,
            'prod_att_size' => $productattribute->size_id,
            'prod_att_material' => $productattribute->material_id,
            'prod_att_prodid' => $productattribute->product_id,
            'prod_id'=>$prod->id,
            'prod_name' =>$prod->name,
        ];
    }
    $status = $request->status;
    $deldate = $request->deldate;
    $discount = $request->discount;
    return view("vendor.new-po-next")
        ->with('status', $status)
        ->with('deldate', $deldate)
        ->with('discount', $discount)
        ->with('product', $product);
}
```

This code is giving the following result (it's the correct result as product1 has 1 variation only but product5 has 3 variations).

[image: Result of the current code]

What I want is that it shows 'product1' and 'product5' (product5 ONCE only).
If the user selects product5, then it shows the rest of the variations to select from.

Please let me know how it can be done!

Comment: First question, what are the relationships between your models? Why can you not just do `$productsupplier->productattributes` instead of going through all these database lookups in a loop?

Comment: The productattribute key is coming into productsuppliers table.

Comment: I did what you said, it's giving this error: Property [productattributes] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: Of course not, if you haven't got proper relationships set up already.

Comment: The productattribute key is coming into productsuppliers table.

Isn't this correct?

Comment: And the product key is coming into the productattribute table. 

Please let me know if you think database is not done correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using Laravel collections, you can convert your array to collection,

```
// After the loop is finished.
$productCollection = collect($product);
$groupedProductCollection = $collection->groupBy('prod_name');

$groupedProduct = $groupedProductCollection->all(); // all method will convert it back to array

// then return the value
return view("vendor.new-po-next")
        ->with('status', $status)
        ->with('deldate', $deldate)
        ->with('discount', $discount)
        ->with('product', $groupedProduct);
```

#### Working

Lets say your product array is like this

```
$product = [
    ['prod_name' => 'product5', 'prod_supp_cost' => '$4'],
    ['prod_name' => 'product5', 'prod_supp_cost' => '$3'],
    ['prod_name' => 'product1', 'prod_supp_cost' => '$6'],
]
```

Then after groupby it will be like,

```
[
        'product5' => [
            ['prod_name' => 'product5', 'prod_supp_cost' => '$4'],
            ['prod_name' => 'product5', 'prod_supp_cost' => '$3'],
        ],
        'product1' => [
            ['prod_name' => 'product1', 'prod_supp_cost' => '$6'],
        ],
    ]
```

Then you you show the array_keys in list and its values separately when the user clicks on it.

#### *EDIT: How to use it in frontend*

```
<select id="" name="">
@foreach(array_keys($groupedProduct) as $product_names)
      <option value="{{ $product_names }}"></option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

If someone clicks then show it using `$groupedProduct[$product_names]`

---

Though the long term and best solution as suggested by @miken32 would be to use eloquent relationships & let relations handle all the querying so that there is no need for a `for loop`.

Comment: also you might have noted that group by increases the array dimension, but in your case it should be fine as you want to show values after the user has clicked on it.

Comment: ``` 
@foreach($groupedProduct as $prods) <option value="">{{$prods['prod_name']}}</option> 
@endforeach 
``` 

On the front-end, would it iterate like this?

Comment: once the user clicks on the option, e.g. Product5, I have made a jquery onClick function. In that function, how do I access the Id and other attributes that are linked to that particular option selection (in this case, the Id & attributes of Product5).

Comment: on onclick trigger, pass the $groupedProduct[$product_names] to the jquery , see this answer to refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61381188/send-data-from-blade-to-onclick-functions-parameters

Comment: Hi @bhucho , I have a question. In the front end, we're accessing the array through the following code: . @foreach(array_keys($groupedProduct) as $prod_name) 
{{$prod_name}} 

When we want to access something else from the array, e.g. prod_id , how do we do that?

Comment: By access how do you want to access, do you want to access it same way as prod_name just replace it, or once user selects then you want to access it?

Comment: Basically, when the user selects the prod_name, it goes to a JavaScript function and then sends ajax query to the backend. I want rest of the details corresponding to the prod_name. E.g. prod_id , so that when the ajax function is called, the ID corresponding to the selected product name is known and further action can be taken upon it. @bhacho

Comment: if `$groupedProduct` array is grouped by `prod_name`, then why are are you not calling it, eg lets say the user select `prod_name` as `product_5`, then `if(count($groupedProduct['product_5'] < 2){ $groupedProduct['product_5']['prod_id']; //would give you id`, if more than 2, then in else block loop through it